# Prevent and Detect Deletion of an Open File

Tags: java, file, delete-file

My Java program opens a file and slowly writes to the file.  When the operation is completed, the program closes the file and moves the file to its final resting place in another directory.  The problem is that as the operation is running, another thread in the same Java program deletes the file.

Windows will not allow the deletion of a file while it is open.  Linux allows the file to be deleted while open.  On NFS file systems, Linux will rename the file and then automatically delete the file when it is closed.  How do I prevent the deletion of files while they are open?

How do I figure out what is deleting the file?  How do I get the call stack of the Java thread in my program that is deleting the file?

Changing the file owner will not work since another thread in the same process is deleting the file.

The program is actively writing to the file so removing the write permission on the file will not work.  Removing the write permission on the directory will not work either since the directory has other files being created and deleted.

The program has 185k lines of code.  There are many calls to `File.delete()` throughout the code.  I could set a breakpoint on `File.delete()`, `Files.delete()`, etc.  However, the program is creating and deleting a lot of files quickly.  This will generate a lot of breakpoint hits burying the needle in the haystack.  I could make the breakpoint conditional but then the program will run very slowly.

Comment: Would it be a good idea to change the permission of the file?

Comment: Unix file permissions can be easily restricted to a single user. Create a user and run your JVM from that user.

Comment: *On Linux, if a file is deleted while opened, then Linux will rename the file and then automatically delete the file when it is closed.*  Not usually.  POSIX-type systems usually just remove the directory entry for the file immediately.  Some filesystems (NFS) do behave as you noted, but that's not normal.

Comment: In Unix file delete, or more exactly unlink, requires write permission to the _containing directory_ not the file itself. (`rm` without `-f` _prompts_ if you don't have write on a file, but succeeds if you confirm.) But if you're creating the file (and dir entry) (by opening it) you need write on the dir for _that_. @Stewart: OP says it's another thread in the same java process, which you can't isolate by userid.

Comment: Assuming no JNI/JNA and your program isn't already running under a `SecurityManager` you could add one with a set of permissions that includes everything you need _except_ delete on the given file (or if suitable all files), which will probably require numerous tries to get right, and see where it throws an exception, unless your code has any handler that swallows the exception. Or you could run under a debugger and set breakpoints at `File.delete` and `Files.delete` and `deleteIfExists` and maybe some others I've missed.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085  Another thread in the same process?  Then surely OP has access to the source, and with detective work can find the culprit.  Unless the codebase is such an awful mess ...........

Comment: @Stewart Given that the program has 185k lines of code and I have access to the source, can you propose the type of detective work to do?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Can you make your `SecurityManager` comment an answer?  This seems like a very viable solution since the `SecurityManager` can dump the call stack of any file being deleted which matches a given pattern without the overhead of conditional breakpoints.  I can also log additional diagnostic information to determine why the deleting thread decided to delete the file.

Comment: @nathan In a completely unknown situation, I would probably begin with a global find/grep of the filename, patterns & variations thereof, or the directory name. If that turned up nothing, a global find/grep for all uses of `java.io.*` or `nio` packages.

Comment: @Stewart I did a global find and went through all 100 uses of `File.delete()`.  A few of them could delete the file in question, but it is hard to say if they do.  I added some logging statements for each one... now to run the code and wait for the issue to reproduce in a day or so.

Comment: @Nathan Any detective work is mostly just aquiring written evidence and waiting. Just ask the police ;)

Comment: A bit late to the show, but most (every?) debugger has _conditional_ breakpoints, meaning you could add a breakpoint, then rightclick->Edit and add a condition on when it should break. The condition would then be if the file's name matched a given filename.

Comment: @oligofren You may have missed this in my question.  If I add a conditional breakpoint, then the program runs too slowly.

Comment: Ah, final sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JDK's file locking mechanism only protects the file from other processes and not threads from the same process.

So, I wrote a read/write file locking framework.  If any thread is holding a read or write lock on a file, then all other threads cannot write or delete the file.  If a thread is holding a read lock on a file, then it can't write or delete the file.  While a thread has a read or write lock on a file, none of the ancestor directories can be deleted.

This framework flushed out the bugs very quickly.  I have not seen a problem since.